# Stack frame preparation

Tags: c, compilation, stack, stack-frame

In order to improve my binary exploitation skills, and deepen my understanding in low level environments I tried solving challenges in pwnable.kr, The third challenge- called `bof` has the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void func(int key){
    char overflowme[32];
    printf("overflow me : ");
    gets(overflowme);   // smash me!
    if(key == 0xcafebabe){
        system("/bin/sh");
    }
    else{
        printf("Nah..\n");
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    func(0xdeadbeef);
    return 0;
}
```

Disassembling the func:

```
0x5655562c <+0>:        push   ebp
0x5655562d <+1>:        mov    ebp,esp
**0x5655562f <+3>:        sub    esp,0x48**
0x56555632 <+6>:        mov    eax,gs:0x14
0x56555638 <+12>:       mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],eax
0x5655563b <+15>:       xor    eax,eax
0x5655563d <+17>:       mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x5655578c
0x56555644 <+24>:       call   0xf7e28b70 <puts>
0x56555649 <+29>:       lea    eax,[ebp-0x2c]
0x5655564c <+32>:       mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x5655564f <+35>:       call   0xf7e280c0 <gets>
0x56555654 <+40>:       cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0xcafebabe
0x5655565b <+47>:       jne    0x5655566b <func+63>
0x5655565d <+49>:       mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x5655579b
0x56555664 <+56>:       call   0xf7dfc8b0 <system>
0x56555669 <+61>:       jmp    0x56555677 <func+75>
0x5655566b <+63>:       mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x565557a3
0x56555672 <+70>:       call   0xf7e28b70 <puts>
0x56555677 <+75>:       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
0x5655567a <+78>:       xor    eax,DWORD PTR gs:0x14
0x56555681 <+85>:       je     0x56555688 <func+92>
0x56555683 <+87>:       call   0xf7ece820 <__stack_chk_fail>
0x56555688 <+92>:       leave  
0x56555689 <+93>:       ret
```

I know how to solve it, but when I disassembled the binary I found out that `esp` creates a stack frame(Highlighted the command where it happens) 0x48 bytes long. And I don't understand why - I thought it'd allocate 32 bytes since the only variable it allocates the stack for is `overflowme`.

Can anybody explain why the stack allocates this many extra bytes?

I have another question,I printed 32 bytes of 'A' into the program and I inspected the stack at the `gets` function line(after the execution). This is the result:

```
0xffffcd20: 0xffffcd3c  0xffffce24  0xf7fa0000  0xf7f9ea60
0xffffcd30: 0x00000000  0xf7fa0000  0xf7ffc840  0x41414141
0xffffcd40: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffcd50: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x93e65400
0xffffcd60: 0x56556ff4  0xf7fa0000  0xffffcd88  0x5655569f
0xffffcd70: 0xdeadbeef  0x00000000  0x565556b9  0x00000000
0xffffcd80: 0xf7fa0000  0xf7fa0000  0x00000000  0xf7dd5fb9
0xffffcd90: 0x00000001  0xffffce24  0xffffce2c  0xffffcdb4
0xffffcda0: 0x00000001  0x00000000  0xf7fa0000  0x00000000
0xffffcdb0: 0xf7ffd000  0x00000000  0xf7fa0000  0xf7fa0000
```

The question is: What are the bytes between the `0x5655569f` (which is the return address) value, and the end of the 'A's? Are there just random junk?

EDIT: Forgot to add, the binary is a 32 bit binary, dynamically linked, with debugging symbols.

Comment: It appears to allocate room for, and store, a so-called canary value - the `mov    eax,gs:0x14` bit - which is checked against for stack corruption on exit. -- The rest of the overhead is for variable alignment purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought about there being a canary, but I ruled it out since I didn't get where the other bytes came from. I guess alignment makes sense!